# enter a view inserts an empty record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i have a problem, every time I enter or refresh a page it inserts a new record

Controller:

```
 public function cobrar(Request $request,$id){

    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'datatable',
        'page_name' => 'custom',
    'has_scrollspy' => 0,
    'scrollspy_offset' => '',

    ];
    $cliente = \App\Models\Eventos::first();
    $cobros = \App\Models\Cobros::where('turno_id',  $request->id)->first();
    $evento = \App\Models\Eventos::where('id' , $id)->with('servicio')->first();
    $servicio = \App\Models\Servicios::where('id', $evento->servicio_id)->first();
    $event = \App\Models\Eventos::find($id);

   


    Cobros::insert([
        'turno_id'       => $request->input("turno_id"),
        'importe'       => $request->input("importe"),
        'servicio_id'       => $request->input("servicio_id"),
      ]);
 



    return view('cobrar',compact('cobros', 'evento', 'servicio', 'event'))->with($data);

  }
```

Image Database:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a check to see if method is get or post...

```
public function cobrar(Request $request,$id){

$data = [
    'category_name' => 'datatable',
    'page_name' => 'custom',
'has_scrollspy' => 0,
'scrollspy_offset' => '',

];
$cliente = \App\Models\Eventos::first();
$cobros = \App\Models\Cobros::where('turno_id',  $request->id)->first();
$evento = \App\Models\Eventos::where('id' , $id)->with('servicio')->first();
$servicio = \App\Models\Servicios::where('id', $evento->servicio_id)->first();
$event = \App\Models\Eventos::find($id);



if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    Cobros::insert([
        'turno_id'       => $request->input("turno_id"),
        'importe'       => $request->input("importe"),
        'servicio_id'       => $request->input("servicio_id"),
      ]);
 
}




    return view('cobrar',compact('cobros', 'evento', 'servicio', 'event'))->with($data);

  }
```